# How do i navigate to a shell tabbed page from a parent shell tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

i have a parent shell tabbed page. i want to be able to navigate from one of the contentPage of this parent page to another shell tabbed page.

Answer (score 7):

Navigation can be performed by specifying a valid absolute URI as an argument to the GoToAsync method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#perform-navigation

On `OnItemSelected` method, invoke the code below.

```
await (App.Current.MainPage as Xamarin.Forms.Shell).GoToAsync("//tabbar/tab/about", true);
```

AppShell.xaml: **Set the route.**

```
<TabBar Route="tabbar">
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>

    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png" Route="tab">
        <ShellContent Route="about" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir, but this is not what i meant. i mean i want to navigate from a tabbed page to another tabbed page with shell

Comment: In the sample, I have two tabbed pages, one is Browse and the other is About. When I click the First item in the Browse tabbed page, it navigate to another About tabbed page. If I missunderstand, please feel free let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir . But i can see u just have a tabbed page with 2 tabs. so u moving from one tab to the another. what i mean is navigating totally from this tabbed page to another tabbed page with its own tabs.

Comment: yea, I have two tabbed pages. But what do you mean `navigating totally from this tabbed page to another tabbed page with its own tabs`? What is the own tabs? Could you provide more details?

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT , may be Godfred Boateng trying to say that how to navigate from Shell TabBar page to normal page of TabbedPage i.e., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Comment: GoToAsync("//tabbar/about" is the correct answer